# Ignoring First line/Column header while reading a file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to read from a source txt file in bash and I want to ignore the first line which is the column.After searching around one solution was to use "sed" with my while loop like below :

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="source2.txt"
#fp=`sed 1d source2.txt`
#echo $fp
sed 1d $filename | while IFS=, read -r accountId ProductId Product
do 
echo "Account $accountId has productId $ProductId and product $Product"
done < $filename
```

But the sed command does not seem to work.Keeps giving all the contents with header.I tried adding double quotes to 1d and also $filename but does not work.

Here is my sample input file content

```
AccountId ProductId Product
300100051205280,300100051161910,content1
300100051199355,300100051161876,content2
```

I am using Editra editor for creating my bash script.Can anyone help me why this is not working.Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use an extra `read` inside a compound command. This is more efficient than using a separate process to skip the first line, and prevents the while loop from running in a subshell (which might be important if you try to set any variables in the body of the loop).

```
{
    read
    while IFS=, read -r accountId ProductId Product
    do 
        echo "Account $accountId has productId $ProductId and product $Product"
    done
} < $filename
```

--

The problem with your original attempt is that you were providing two sources of input to the while loop (via the pipe from `sed`, and via an input reduction). Dropping the input redirection would fix that.

```
sed 1d $filename | while IFS=, read -r accountId ProductId Product
do 
    echo "Account $accountId has productId $ProductId and product $Product"
done
```

Comment: That works, too. I prefer to use as few external tools as possible if writing shell code (an `awk` script is probably better than pure `bash` here). I only included the corrected `sed` example to demonstrate what the root problem was.

Comment: What if your headers have spaces between them - like 'Product Id' instead of ProductId

Comment: @Righto The entire header line is being ignored; it doesn't matter what is in the header line. If you want help with parsing such a line, you'll need to ask in another question.

Comment: Is there any way someone could quickly talk me through how this is working - I want to use it but not without knowing exactly what it's doing...

Comment: @Raph117 Post a new question pointing out exactly what you are having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 8):

Other answers are much more technically savvy, but I have a simple hack that works quite well, as long as the header's first title isn't changed.

```
while IFS=, read -r accountId ProductId Product
do 
  # If accountId matches Header line value, continue
  if [[ $accountId == "AccountId" ]]; then
     continue
  fi
  #Do your other things, assume all values are real
done < $filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant which skips the first iteration by checking the existance of a variable:

```
while IFS=, read -r accountId ProductId Product; do
  # skip header
  if [[ ! $first_line ]]; then
    first_line=1
    continue
  fi
  # process
done < $filename
```

Or skip the first line with `tail -n +2` (which is technically the same as `sed 1d`):

```
while IFS=, read -r accountId ProductId Product; do
  # process 
done < <(tail -n +2 $filename)
```